# iOS11 UIRefreshControl and UISearchController has some issue when refreshing

Tags: ios, objective-c

There is some views with white background color in the figure during when i pulldown the tableview，please tell me how to remove that very thin white strip out. I'm sure that the white line is the tableview.backgroundColor.

[image]

Below is my setup code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Init Data
    self.dataArray = @[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",
                       ];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:SP_RGBColor(64-20,194-20,160-20)];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];

    NSDictionary *textTitleOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys :
                                      [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                      [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                      [UIFont systemFontOfSize : 21.0],UITextAttributeFont,
                                      nil];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:textTitleOptions];


    // Init Search
    MyResultsViewController *resultsController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyResultsViewController"];

    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:resultsController];
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = resultsController;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];



    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;


    if(@available(iOS 11, *) )
    {
            //self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = YES;
            self.tableView.insetsContentViewsToSafeArea = YES;
            self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController;


    }else
    {
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
            self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(self.searchController.searchBar.frame));
    }


    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshContent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
```